# How can we access the first row's value in the Window in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to access the value of the very first row in the window of DataFrame in Spark.

| Account | Transaction | Created Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acc1 | T1 | 2021-08-01 |
| Acc1 | T2 | 2021-08-02 |
| Acc1 | T3 | 2021-08-03 |
| Acc1 | T4 | 2021-08-04 |
| Acc2 | T1 | 2021-08-03 |
| Acc2 | T2 | 2021-08-03 |
| Acc2 | T3 | 2021-08-07 |

If above one is the dataframe, I want to find out the first row's Created Date value when window partitionBy("Account").

| Account | Transaction | Created Date | First Txn Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acc1 | T1 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-01 |
| Acc1 | T2 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-01 |
| Acc1 | T3 | 2021-08-03 | 2021-08-01 |
| Acc1 | T4 | 2021-08-04 | 2021-08-01 |
| Acc2 | T1 | 2021-08-03 | 2021-08-03 |
| Acc2 | T2 | 2021-08-03 | 2021-08-03 |
| Acc2 | T3 | 2021-08-07 | 2021-08-03 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spark sql.

If the first transaction for an account is always the earliest transaction then the following would provide the desired results.

```sql
SELECT
    Account,
    Transaction,
    CreatedDate,
    MIN(CreatedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Account) as FirstTxnDate
FROM
   my_temp_view_or_table
```

Here I've used the `MIN` as a window function to achieve the earliest transaction for each partition/group/account.

Comment: is there any other way to access the column values of first row?
It may not be always sorted based on that column.

Comment: The `MIN(CreatedDate)` doesn't require your data to be sorted. It will always find the earliest date in that group. If you would like to retrieve the first record in a group when having your data ordered by a nother column you could always use the [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/api/sql/#first_value) function eg `FIRST_VALUE(ColumnYouWantFirstValueFor) OVER (PARTITION BY Account Order By ColumnYouWantYourDataOrderedBy)`